# How to make typecasted variable appear as key rather than value using SendKeys

Tags: windows, powershell, sendkeys

```
$a = [char]65
$w1 = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$w1.AppActivate('Untitled - Notepad') 
Sleep 1
Write-Host $a
$w1.SendKeys($a);
```

In a PowerShell script I am trying to use the `SendKeys` command to make the letter `A` appear in Notepad by typecasting the variable `$a` as a `[char]` with the value of `65`. This gives me the expected result when I run the line:

```
Write-Host $a
```

(`A` appears in PowerShell)

But whenever the following line runs:

```
$w1.SendKeys($a);
```

The numbers `65` are put into Notepad instead of `A`.

Why do these two lines produce different outputs when given the same parameter and what can I do to make the variable `$a` output the character `A` in both situations?

Answer (score 2):

Because `char` is an integral type, `SendKeys` is treating `$a` as an integer. You can get the same behavior by passing in `65` directly:

```
$w1.SendKeys(65); # Sends "65" to Notepad
```

---

To fix the problem, you need to explicitly give  `SendKeys` a string argument. Easiest way to do this is to enclose `$a` in quotes:

```
$w1.SendKeys("$a");
```